# Running Hadoop with YARN in IDEA throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, classnotfoundexception

I would like to run a simple Hadoop *WordCount* client program with single-node pseudo-distributed cluster. This project is created by `Maven` with `hadoop-client:2.7.7` dependency in IDEA, and the code is from [WordCount v1.0](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.10.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Source_Code).

But I have some troubles in running with YARN mode in IDEA. The followings are what I have tried:

**1. IDEA: only HDFS (works)**

```java
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
```

It works in `local` mode.

**2. Jar: HDFS + YARN (works)**

The code does not contain any `conf` part. Instead, I prepared a simple `cluster.xml` as conf:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>localhost:8032</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I packaged it into a Jar (`mvn package`), and then ran it

```bash
./bin/hadoop -jar test.jar com.example.WordCount -conf cluster.xml
```

It works in `yarn` mode.

Note that in order to specify the `-conf` option directly, the class is declared as:

```java
public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool
```

**3. IDEA: HDFS + YARN (not work)**

However, I updated the conf part into the following, and ran it in IDEA:

```java
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "localhost:8032");
```

It reports an error

> java.lang.classNotFoundException: class com.example.WordCount$TokenizerMapper not found

Why does it raise an error here? How to fix it?

Comment: FWIW, no one really writes Mapreduce anymore. Also, arguments `-conf cluster.xml` are not doing anything unless you changed the source code, however that XML file should be placed in `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` variable path, not passed to `hadoop -jar`

Comment: 1. I know Spark would be much better, but I am just curious. 2. Yes, `-conf` option does nothing by default. But it works if we use `WordCount extends Configured implements Tool` (this method is introduced in "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide"). Anyway, I am just curious about why it raises a classnotfound exception here. @OneCricketeer

Comment: I'm not particularly sure. I haven't had issues [running my code](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/mapreduce-sandbox) in IntelliJ

Comment: After some investigation, I think I'm closing the answer: in YARN mode, it must upload the Jar to HDFS in some way, but this is impossible in IntelliJ directly. An alternative way is to specify the `mapred.jar` conf. Anyway, packaging jar is necessary in YARN mode.

Comment: `hadoop -jar` takes a local file, I thought, but if you are using Maven, you could look into the Wagon plugin, I think it is called, which can SCP your JAR into Linux edgenode after the maven-assembly / shade plugins create an uber jar. Then you could follow that with the exec-maven-plugin to run `hadoop fs -put ... 
 && hadoop -jar` commands. However, a Makefile to do the same would be a bit simpler